# How to use VBA in Excel to refresh and save/print to PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing, acrobat

I want to print quickly to PDF.

Here is the "work flow":

> 1 - `F9` to refresh. I think `Calculate` does the job.
>   2 - `F9` to refresh. Print `ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4` (whole workbook) and save as `1.pdf`
>   3 - `F9` to refresh. Print `ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4` (whole workbook) and save as `2.pdf`
>   4 - `F9` to refresh. Print `ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4` (whole workbook) and save as `3.pdf`
>   etc. to repeat say 10 times, up to `10.pdf`.

I manually disabled "view PDF result".

This is edited from a recorded macro and will give me several copies and ask for the `filename` if I use `Adobe PDF` printer.

```
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Copies:=1
```

How can I adapt this so I don't have to manually input the file name as `1.pdf, 2.pdf 3.pdf` etc.?

[image]

System and packages in use:

```
MS Excel 2016 (X64)
Adobe Acrobat XI (with Adobe PDF printer)
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while performing those steps?

Comment: I have a working macro that repeatedly refresh and promotes print. But I want it to be more "intelligent" in a way I don't even have to type in the file name when printing to PDF. The recorded macro only do "refresh" and "print", which still asks for file name (PDF).

Comment: are you printing the same workbook over and over? or are you opening new workbooks, printing and saving?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your 'working macro' so it can be viewed to allow someone to help you.

Comment: @GMalc I have edited as requested. Thanks.

Comment: @learnAsWeGo I use the same workbook, `F9` to refresh it before printing.

Answer (score 0):

After a full day of playing around, I have finally managed to do it! Since we don't exactly need to have `Acrobat PDF` printer to save as PDF files. Excel (VBA) supports this regardless.

So here is the code:

```
    For n = 1 To max
        Calculate
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= sPath & "\"& n &".pdf"
    Next n
```

where `sPath` is the location for the exported files.

The solution is much easier to than expected!  But as I have never done anything with `VBA`, this took about 5 hours of research!